# Sort bibliography by origdate

Tags: biblatex, sorting

Is there a way to sort a bibliography using origdate as a criterion.

I tried to define a new sorting scheme but it doesn't work. What's wrong with it.

Minimal example :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=verbose,sorting=noyt]{biblatex}
% To make origdate visible
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
     \iffieldundef{origyear}{}{\setunit{}
    \mkbibparens{\printorigdate}
    \newunit}
}

% New sorting scheme

\DeclareSortingScheme{noyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{sortorigdate}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
  \field{origdate}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
}

\addbibresource{example.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The example.bib file :

```
@book{a,
  author       = {Doe, John},
  title        = {Another Super Book},
  date         = 2006,
  origdate = {1994},
  publisher        = {Publisher}
}
@book{b,
  author       = {Doe, John},
  title        = {Super Book},
  date         = 2006,
  origdate = {1991},
  publisher        = {Publisher}
}

@book{c,
  author       = {Sponge, Bob},
  title        = {My Life},
  date         = 2007,
  publisher        = {Publisher}
}
```

And the result :

[image]

I'd like "Super book" to be the first on the list.

Comment: I don't think you need the line `\field{sortorigdate}` -- it looks kinda made-up -- but you probably should change `\field{origdate}` to `\field{origyear}`.

Comment: jon is absolutely right there. `sortorigdate` doesn't exist. And for proper sorting you need `\field{origyear}` (analogous to `\field{sortyear}` and `\field{year}`). I think it would make more sense to move the `\field{origdate}` in the same `\sort` block as `sortyear` & `year`. But that is for you to decide.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work with origyear. Thanks!

Comment: @jon Since your answer solved the issue, would you mind writing up an answer?

Comment: @jon Sorry to bother you again. But I would feel a bit guilty if this question remained without an answer, because I told Texxet off for answering themselves without asking you to answer first and they then deleted their answer.

Comment: @moewe -- Sorry, I meant to add an answer, but my time for TeX is sadly very much diminished these days. Will try to get to it this weekend.

Comment: @Texxet -- Undelete your answer if you like. I'll vote for it. If someone wants to add a fuller answer, they should feel free to do so. (Totally swamped these days....)

Answer (score 1):

Conforming with the commentaries (thanks to jon and moewe), here is a correct sorting scheme :

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{noyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{origyear}
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
}
```